# php "iframe" load SP Modal dialog

Tags: modal-dialog

I have a php page insert into a PageViewer Webpart, in the php page, I have a button and I want that when you click on it, it will display a sharepoint modal windows in the parent sharepoint page (diplaying an url)

In the php page I tried :

```
function ShowDialog()
    {

    var options = parent.SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 700;
    options.height = 500;
    options.url = "myurl.html";
    parent.SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
```

......

```
<input name="test" value="test" type="button" onclick="javascript:ShowDialog();">
```

or

insert the function in a webpart content editor :

```
function ShowDialog()
    {

    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.width = 700;
    options.height = 500;
    options.url = "myurl.html";
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
```

and in the php page :

```
<input name="test" value="test" type="button" onclick="javascript:parent.ShowDialog();">
```

......
or :

```
<input name="test" value="test" type="button" onclick="javascript:window.parent.ShowDialog();">
```

but nothing work. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I finally find one working Solution:
The fact is that the iframe and the page are not store on the same server and so, the access to parent.function() is denied.

The solution is to store one html page (here proxy.html) page on the SharePoint with this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  // This event is fired when you change my window size
  window.onresize = function(){

    // Retrieve the hash of my url, ex: #action:value
    var hash = document.location.hash;

    if(hash != ''){

      // Split # to extract "action:value"
      var hash = hash.split('#');

      // Split : to extract "action" and "value"
      var params = hash[1].split(':');

      switch(params[0]){



        case 'sh_dial':            
          // Call my parent funtion ShowDialog

          window.top.ShowDialog(params[1]);
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

In my Iframe (php page) :

It's need to display the proxy.html page in an iframe

```
<iframe src="http://sharepointsite/Documents/proxy.html" id="iframeProxy" width="0" height="0" ...></iframe>
```

and adding this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Here you can call this function to make the job by the proxy
    function gotoAction(action) {

      var iframeProxy = document.getElementById('iframeProxy');

      // Step 1: put the parameters you want to give to the iframe proxy in the hash
      var src =  iframeProxy.src.split('#');
      iframeProxy.src = src[0] + '#' + action;

      // Step 2: change the size of the iframe proxy to execute his resize event (see proxyA.html)
      document.getElementById('iframeProxy').width = parseInt(document.getElementById('iframeProxy').width) + 1;

      return false;

    }
</script>
```

Finally on the Button (Php page) :

```
<input name="test" value="test" type="button" onclick="gotoAction('sh_dial:Param');">
```